# Wrong Path environment variable in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, msbuild, nuget

When I check Jenkins's `SystemInfo` I see there different `Path` variable than when I check Windows `Path` variable. Here is a comparison: the lefts side from Jenkins `SystemInfo`, the right - from Windows.

[image]

The Visual Studio 2017 msbuild is picked by nuget.exe and fails to restore .net core 3.1 projects. I thought Jenkins inherit `Path` from the system and can't understand where the additional values come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the source of Jenkins environment variables. Since Jenkins runs as windows service, it inherits variables from `services.exe` that inherits from `wininit.exe`. So if you changed environment variables (as I did) and want to force Jenkins to update its variables it's not enough to restart Jenkins service, you have to restart Windows or `explorer.exe`